# Submit selected option in a scrollable <select> in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So here's my html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1 class="table-title">Employees</h1>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Role</th>
          <th>References</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let tempEmployee of employees">
          <td class="align-middle">{{ tempEmployee.userName }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ tempEmployee.email }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">{{ tempEmployee.roleId }}</td>
          <td class="align-middle">
            <a routerLink="/projects">Assigned Projects</a>
            <br />
            <a href="#">Assigned Tickets</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Select 1 or multiple users</h4>
    <select id="user-list" multiple size="employees.length" >
      <option
      *ngFor="let employee of employees; let indexOfEmployee=index;"
      value="indexOfEmployee"
      >{{ employee.userName }}</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submit" type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm confused on how I can know if an option is selected so that in the component on the onSubmit() function i can check if an option is selected and submit it. Also multiple options can be selected.
I tried to console.dir the option element to see if it has a selected property but maybe i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

some quick and easy javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("user-id").length; i++){
  if(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].selected == true){
    console.log("selected")
  }
}
```

Comment: uhm if selected in a property of option, why cant i access it and pass it with two way data binding?

Comment: so you only have one option tag. And not multiple? because you can append options with vanilla javascript.